# How to create a custom column with correlative numbers

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to create a new column with the id of each line so **i need to generate a serie of correlative number for each of my rows in the table**.

**The image with my table and the code I tried:**
[image]

I tried with this code but returns me an ERROR:

`APTPreguntaId = GENERATESERIES(1;17)`

I started using Power Bi recently so I'm still trying to understand the dynamics of DAX.

Comment: It would help if you show us the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do this is in the query editor. Open the query editor and select your table.

Select your table and press tab: Add Column.

Here you will find the index Column button

[image]